# Notifications system getting all new records

Tags: php, json, ajax, while-loop

So I've built all of the basic functionality, but with a major flaw.  I search from the last id inserted which is fine.. But the error is when I get to the PHP. I search for MAX id and it sends back the last record obviously.. But if a user does three actions that sends a notification to you, then the other two don't show via the call, only when the page refreshes.

So what would I have to change to get all the notifications from the database when each call is made from the last id it searches for in the front end? I presume maybe a while loop in the PHP page rather than the max id.  but then how would the back end select ALL new data from the front ends last max id?

So this is what I have.

```
   <?  

$user1_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_SESSION['id']);
$call="select MAX(notification_id) AS notification_id ,notification_status,notification_targetuser,notification_triggeredby,notification_throughurl from notifications WHERE notification_targetuser='$user1_id' AND notification_status=1 ORDER BY notification_id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $chant=mysqli_query($mysqli,$call) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));


while($notification=mysqli_fetch_array($chant)){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

var notification_id="<?php echo $notification['notification_id']?>";
var notification_targetuser="<?php echo $notification['notification_targetuser']?>";
var notification_triggeredby="<?php echo $notification['notification_triggeredby']?>";
function loadIt() {

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "viewajax.php?notification_id="+notification_id+"&notification_targetuser="+notification_targetuser+"&notification_triggeredby="+notification_triggeredby,   
dataType:"json",
success: function(data){
if(data.notification_id>notification_id){
 $("#notif_ui"+notification_id).prepend('<div class="notif_text"><div id="notif_actual_text-" class="notif_actual_text"><img border="1" src="userimages/cropped'+data['notification_triggeredby']+'.jpg" onerror=this.src="userimages/no_profile_img.jpeg" width="40" height="40" ><br /><a href="'+data['notification_throughurl']+'">'+data['notification_content']+' </a><br />'+data['notification_time']+'<br/></div></div></div><hr/>');
 i = parseInt($("#mes").text()); $("#mes").text((i+data.num)); 

    if(!data.notification_id.length) {
   //no results...
   return;
}
notification_id = data.notification_id; 
}
}
});
}
setInterval(loadIt, 10000);   
 </script>
```

PHP

```
$json = array();
    $com=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select MAX(notification_id) AS notification_id,notification_content,notification_time,notification_triggeredby,notification_throughurl from notifications where notification_id > '$id' AND notification_targetuser=".$_GET['notification_targetuser']." AND notification_triggeredby=".$_GET['notification_triggeredby']."  AND notification_status=1");

    $num = mysqli_num_rows($com);
    if($num>0){

        $json['num'] = $num;
    }else{
        $json['num'] = 0;
    }
    $resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($com);
    $json['notification_id'] = $resultArr['notification_id'];
    $json['notification_content'] = $resultArr['notification_content'];
    $json['notification_throughurl'] = $resultArr['notification_throughurl'];
    $json['notification_triggeredby'] = $resultArr['notification_triggeredby'];
    $json['notification_time'] = $resultArr['notification_time'];
    mysqli_free_result($com);

    echo json_encode($json);
    }
```

Comment: Okay I've done a little more research on this as there doesn't seem to be much.
Apparently searching the max record on the client side and then comparing it with an id > more than that record in the select on the server side.

Solution: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665227/whats-the-fastest-way-to-poll-a-mysql-table-for-new-rows)

Answer (score 0):

I in fact used  `mysqli_free_result($com);`within the while loop preventing more than one set of results returning and therefore removed this from the query.